# cakephp3で作ったアプリケーションをherokuに公開できない。HTTP ERROR 500が出る

Tags: php, cakephp, heroku

#### 前提・実現したいこと

https://qiita.com/uedatakeshi/items/9712cd4632209389445a#heroku%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A

上記のherokuの設定を参考にして作業していますが、なぜかアプリケーションを公開できません。
Procfileの作成からherokuプッシュまで、完全に同じ手順で設定しています。

(まずはトップページを表示させたいと思っているので、データベースの設定はまだです)

webrootのindex.phpでcakeのサーバーが見つからないとありますが、どうしたらよいか...
vendorが必要なのでは？と思い、vendorを入れたりもしてました。

考えらえる原因は何でしょうか？
完全に詰まってしまったので回答もらえると嬉しいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

HTTP ERROR 500

#### 以下、herokuのログ

```
2019-01-26T10:47:18.293157+00:00 app[web.1]: [26-Jan-2019 10:47:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cake\Http\Server' not found in /app/webroot/index.php:37
2019-01-26T10:47:18.293173+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2019-01-26T10:47:18.293175+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 {main}
2019-01-26T10:47:18.293251+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/webroot/index.php on line 37
2019-01-26T10:47:18.293790+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.43.234.10 - - [26/Jan/2019:10:47:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
2019-01-26T10:47:18.294450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=thawing-gorge-19673.herokuapp.com request_id=b62d8d05-e86f-4b0a-91da-9d433257ea88 fwd="49.106.188.51" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=169 protocol=https
```

#### 試したこと

config/bootstrap.phpに追加するコードの順番を変更
gitignoreでvendorを入れるよう設定変更

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

cakePHP3.6.12

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/171020

Comment: vendorフォルダがほしいということはcomposerを利用していますか？